# Firebase SDK - Will onchildchanged be triggered in the same order as the setValue are triggered?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wondering if the Firebase SDKs onChildChanged() will be triggered in the same order as my application is triggering the setValue. Here's an example:

```
private void testAdds ()
{
    this.mFBD.getReference("PATH/").child(ID1).setValue(1);
    this.mFBD.getReference("PATH/").child(ID2).setValue(2);
    this.mFBD.getReference("PATH/").child(ID3).setValue(3);
}

...

@Override
public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
{
    // Will this be triggered in the same order as my setValue(1-3) commands??
    // Or isn't this guaranteed?
}
```

If it's not guaranteed that it will be received in the same order in the onChildChanged or onChildAdded as the order setValue was triggered, how can I change this to be certain that they will be in order on the other side too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if the Firebase SDKs onChildChanged will be triggered in the same order as my application is triggering the setValue.

It might happen, but there is no guarantee for that. If you want to be 100% sure that the second value is written after the first value, then you should write the second value, once the first write operation is complete. This can be done by attaching a listener, as you can see in the following lines of code:

```
this.mFBD.getReference("PATH/").child(ID1).setValue(1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            this.mFBD.getReference("PATH/").child(ID2).setValue(2);
        }
    }
});
```

In this way, you are sure that the order is the one you want. If you need the same thing for all three, the same principle applies. Attach another listener to the second write operation and perform the third one when the second one is complete.